# Securing Livewire POST Data Against XSS Attacks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to prevent XSS attacks. I am using HTMLPurifier and Livewire. When I post data from Livewire and use the code(middleware):

```
<?php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $originalInput = $input;
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    array_walk_recursive($input, function (&$value) use ($purifier) {
        $value = $purifier->purify($value);
    });
    $request->replace($input);
    return $next($request);
}
?>
```

It throws a 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null' error. How can I secure all POST data through Livewire?